# CMake 3.27 ExternalProject_Add not downloading

Tags: cmake, dependency-management

I've been using CMakes `ExternalProject_Add` functionality to handle dependencies for some time now. Today I decided to use a different workstation which had the newer CMakes 3.27 installed.

I noticed that it suddenly didn't find my dependency libraries such as OpenSSL.

Usually I would have a dependency file such as "openssl.cmake", which could look like this:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(OSSL
    URL https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/download/openssl-3.1.2/openssl-3.1.2.tar.gz
    URL_MD5 1d7861f969505e67b8677e205afd9ff4
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/OPENSSL
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND
    cd <SOURCE_DIR> &&
    rm -f CMakeCache.txt &&
    ./Configure &&
    make
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )

set(OSSL_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/OPENSSL/src/OSSL/include)
set(OSSL_LIB_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/OPENSSL/src/OSSL)
```

A file which I would then include from my primary CMakeLists.txt

Might not be the 100% correct way, but it has always worked. Now it doesn't. CMake does see the file, create the "deps" folder, and populate it with "build", "stamp", "tmp" folders under "OPENSSL".

However, it never actually downloads the OpenSSL file. I've tried multiple examples online, I've tried using git instead for the tar.gz file, I've tried with all kinds of different options - but I simply can't get it to download and run. I'm not getting *any* errors, and in the `build.ninja` file, it looks like it's suppose to download it. It simply, doesn't.

What is it I am missing with the new CMake?